# Propositional logic: WFF of "neither A nor B"

Tags: propositional-calculus

In propositional logic, how should the sentence "neither A nor B" be converted into a Well Formed Formula? Is it $\sim(A \lor B)$ or should it be $\sim(A \land B)$? Can it be interrupted both ways? I need a little help understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Neither A nor B" is "not A and not B" and is formalized with [Logical NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) i.e. $(¬A ∧ ¬B)$ that is equivalent to $¬(A ∨ B)$.

You can check with a simple truth table that $¬(A ∨ B)$ and $¬(A ∧ B)$ are not equivalent [when $A$ is TRUE and $B$ is FALSE, the first formula is FALSE, while the second one is TRUE].

Comment: Dear sir, I know that it is true that if $\phi$ is a wff and $psi$ is a wff of length less than $phi$ ,then than the sum of the number of occurrences of atoms and connectives of $\psi$ will be less than that of $\phi$, but how to prove this fact-I tried induction but failed-, thank you

Comment: @Logic - what is the connection with this 4-years old post?

Comment: The "length" is the number of symbols: a symbol is either an occurrence of an atom or a connective. Thus...

Comment: Sir the length also includes brackets, this problem is paining me and thought that you were the only one who could help me

Comment: @Logic - by induction on the number of connectives. (i) Base case $n=1$; the formula must be either $(\lnot p)$ or $(p \lor q)$. The first one has $l=4$ while the second one has $l=5$; thus the condition of theorem applies. We have that $\#(\lnot p)=2$ while $\#(p \lor q)=3$. Thus the property holds for $n=1$ and the Base case is proved. Next (ii) Induction step...

Comment: Sorry sir I can’t figure out the induction step thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"Neither ...nor" is the negation of " OR" ; hence its name " NOR"

So neither A nor B means

- ~ (A OR B)  [ read : it's not the case that (A is true OR B is true)]

which is equivalent, using DeMorgan's law, to

- ~ A & ~ B.

An Or statement is true as soon as at least one of the conjuncts is true; a NOR statement is false  as soon as one of the 2 sentences is true.

Answer (score 0):

- in order to be true , the sentence ~ ( A&B) requires that one ( at least) out of the two propositions to be false; and the falsehood of only one proposition is sufficient for ~ (A & B) to be true
- the truth conditions of " neither A nor B" are different ; in order to be true, it requires  BOTH propositions to be false.
- since " neither A nor B" and "~ (A&B)" do not have the same truth conditions, they are not equivalent.